# CSS3 transform: perspective doesn't want to work in Opera < 21

Tags: css, transform, opera

I want to apply this transformation:
transform: perspective(500px) rotateY(75deg);

Opera 22 display this transform fine but Opera 20 doesn't, how to fix this?

Comment: Are you sure Opera < 21 is even suppose to support transform? http://caniuse.com/

Comment: @ImranBughio, http://dev.opera.com/articles/understanding-3d-transforms/

>Opera 15 adds a lot of goodies under its hood, including three-dimensional CSS transforms.

Comment: with -webkit prefix doesn't work too.

Comment: Use the command with its vendor prefix: `-o-transfrom`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I am aware, transforms are supported since Opera 15, with the vendor prefix:

```
element {
    -o-transform: perspective(500px) rotateY(75deg);
    transfrom: perspective(500px) rotateY(75deg);
}
```

This should allow you to tackle all versions of Opera greater than 15.